# For all functions : ℝ → ℝ and for all subsets ,  ′ ⊆ ℝ, ( ∩  ′ ) = () ∩ ( ′ ).

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

This statement is supposed to be false.

I think it is true since if I let f be an identity function and if I establish X {1,2} and X' {1,4},  ∩  ′ = {1} which would mean ( ∩  ′) = {1}. If f({1,2}) = {1,2} and f({1,4}) = {1,4}, then f(X) ∩ f(X') = {1}.

I've tested a few cases but can't seem to find a case that returns false for this statement.

I need some help identifying the flaw in my logic. Thank you.

Comment: This statement is true for the identity function. But it may not be true for other functions.

Comment: The statement says **for all functions** $f$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: check when $f$ is constant and sets are disjoint....

Comment: @quester. In that case won't ( ∩  ′) and  f(X) ∩ f(X') be equal to the null set which still makes them both equal?

Comment: i.e. $f\equiv-7$ then $f(X \cap X') = f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$ and $f(X) \cap f(X') = \{-7\} \cap \{-7\} = \{-7\}$, or when $f(x) = tan(x)$ xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Can you come up with an example of a function $f$ and two sets $A,B$ such that $A \cap B = \emptyset$ byt $f(A)$ and $f(B)$ have a common element?